# Using PHP to connect to MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create some very basic php code that will let me know If i have successfully connected to my MySQL database. Using MySQLi, I have found out that this is the best way of creating a connection:

```
$connection = mysqli_connect(host, username, password, dbname);
```

and then I saw that you can test to see if you are connected by using an if statement like this:

```
if(!$connection){
    echo "connection failed"
}
else{
    echo "Successful connection"
}
```

I believe what I am having the most difficult time trying to understand is the parameters for the mysqli_connect function. I understand that I need the username, password, and database name from MySQL, however I am fluttering at what needs to go where it says "host". Is anyone familiar with connecting to a MySQL database that could help me out?

Comment: `host, username, password, dbname` < those are constants, you do know that right?

Comment: *"Is anyone familiar with connecting to a MySQL database that could help me out?"* - It's in the manual https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner I know that I need to put actually information where those words are, I just am not sure what to put where host is.

Comment: Hey, read the manual: host is an ip-adress, or localhost or socket path.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner That is basically what I have at that link, but where does the "127.0.0.1" where host is come from?

Comment: @ANON That's the standard IP address for `localhost`.

Comment: Going down the `mysqli` road may be a bad investment if your time. PDO is a much more flexible, more fully featured database layer that can do everything `mysqli` can and then some. It's not MySQL specific, it has named placeholders, and above all else, a much more sensible API. If you're not too committed, it's worth switching.

Answer (score 2):

The database doesn't have to run on the same computer as the PHP application, it can be on a network server. The `host` parameter is the name or IP address of the server.

If the database is running on the same machine, use `"localhost"` as the `host` argument.

Comment: Okay so if i have the web server running and the MySQL database open on the same machine then I can simply just put local host and the PHP will know to connect to the MySQL?

Comment: Unless there's something wrong with the MySQL configuration on the machine.

Comment: Okay, so i put my edited code at the end of my question, this is currently just displaying the code into the web browser. Any idea why that is happening?

Comment: That's a webserver configuration problem. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121495/php-code-is-not-being-executed-instead-code-shows-on-the-page

Comment: You also have `-` instead of `_` in `mysqli_connect`.

Comment: yeah i am working from a virtual machine so i cannot copy and paste so i had to retype all of that. the - is an _ in the actual code I have but ill check our your link

Answer (score 1):

A server is anything that handle its clients, Host is where a server is "hosted", for example if I have my birthday party tonight at my home then I would say, "I am hosting the party at this *address*", Similarly in computer world, the "address" part is the *IP of the server*

> **"host" simply means IP of the mysql server.**

MySQL server on the same computer is hosted on IP "127.0.0.1" also named as "localhost" ( by default ), Hopefully this answers your question.